# How can I increase the 20-minute lifespan of contexts

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

As I read in the Google documentation “all contexts expire after 20 minutes of becoming active” (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-input-output). What I was wondering is if there is a way to extend this limit. For example, if I store an mp3 playlist in my context so that I can play next audio at the end of the current one, if the duration of the current mp3 exceeds 20 minutes I lose the context and any information on the next mp3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup 2 things:
Your own webhook server.
A DB of your preference (I chose MongoDB) to store user data identifyied by an unique chat id, and it can be retrieved diferently from each platform that you integrate your chatbot with.
For example: on facebook you can use the userID of the user that is having a conversation with your bot as uniqueID, on twilio you can use the phonenumber and on your own chat UI for web you can stablish your own ID (usually a timestamp) as a parameter of the request you send to Dialogflow and store it on the localStorage of the client browser. So the next time the user chats with your bot within that same browser, you can get his data by using this uniqueID.

For facebook you can get the userid  by using:
agent.originalRequest.payload.data.sender.id
For twilio:
agent.originalRequest.payload.data.From
For web (it depends of the variable that you send to the API)
agent.originalRequest.payload.data.{variable}

Using this uniqueID you can create your own DB registry for each user, get, retrieve or store data and make your contexts stay forever.

PS: Let me know If I was clear, its 4:34 AM lol, I can comment on this to clear any doubts.
Peace!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found any working solution. I hope someone can help

Comment: I found a way but you need to run your own webhook server and use a DB of your preference. You can store info, literally forever by using an unique chat id that comes with each plataform. I will explain more on my own answer.